# Hosting in the UK, Trace Route goes to US

Tags: web-hosting

OK so I am a bit confused as to why when I do a trace route for a domain hosted in the UK has some cities in the US in the hops?

```
**Hop**        **Host name**  
1              -
2              xe-4-2-0.er2.dfw2.us.above.net  
3              ae2.cr2.dfw2.us.above.net
4              ae4.cr1.dfw2.us.above.net
5              xe-4-2-0.cr1.iah1.us.above.net
6              ae2.cr1.dca2.us.above.net
7              ae4.mpr2.lhr2.uk.above.net
8              ae5.mpr1.lhr1.uk.above.net
9              94.31.41.142.ipyx-068416-002-zyo.above.net
10             -
11             2e1c32b5.lon.100tb.com
Trace Complete
```

If im not mistaken it is going to the states too, whilst i am in the UK and the server also in the UK, why is it going there?
Does it defeat the purpose of hosting in the UK?

Comment: Which trace route tool are you using?

Comment: I am using http://network-tools.com/ will that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using network-tools.com will that make a difference?

Yes, network-tools.com is in the US! When you do a trace on that site it is performing a trace from that server (in the US) to your server (in the UK), not from your machine to your server.

To check the trace from your machine (in the UK), you need to run a trace tool on your machine.

Comment: actually did that as soon as you wrote the above comment, and there weren't any us locations. Thank you!